# Как проверить какие версии пакета доступны для загрузки?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Как понять какие версии браузера доступны для установки в моей системе?

```
  apt-cache search chromium-browser
```

Comment: apt-cache show.

Comment: Он показывает только 2 пакета. 
69 и 65 версию. А мне нужна 49. получается в ubuntu 18.04 установить более старую версию не получиться?

Comment: Да, из репозитория не получится, скачивайте нужную версию из других источников и надейтесь, что она окажется совместима с вашей системой

Comment: Если нужна любая версия пакет в любое время смените ОС на NixOS или Guix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> apt-cache policy foo bar ...
>
> Проверяет статус пакетов foo bar ....
>
> apt-cache show foo bar ... | less
>
> Проверяет информацию по пакетам foo bar ....

Вот тут, можно ознакомиться детальнее: http://qref.sourceforge.net/Debian/quick-reference/ch-package.ru.html